# Getting and exception when I'm trying to create java web service from wsdl in JDeveloper

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, jdeveloper

I have a custom project in jdeveloper, I'm trying to create a service web from wsdl option, I open the wizard and I select any wsdl and I Finish the wizard I have an error: "Fetching WSDL and mapping files failed for the following reason

[image]

This is the output.

```
     WARNING: Fetching WSDL and mapping files failed for the following reason:
oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.GenerationException: Fetching WSDL and mapping files failed for the following reason:
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.java.generator.CreateClasses.makeLocalWSDL(CreateClasses.java:604)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.java.generator.CreateClasses.action(CreateClasses.java:184)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.generator.GeneratorAction.run(GeneratorAction.java:142)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at oracle.bali.ewt.dialog.JEWTDialog.runDialog(JEWTDialog.java:399)
    at oracle.bali.ewt.dialog.JEWTDialog.runDialog(JEWTDialog.java:360)
    at oracle.ide.dialogs.ProgressBar.start(ProgressBar.java:544)
    at oracle.ide.dialogs.ProgressBar.start(ProgressBar.java:395)
    at oracle.ide.dialogs.ProgressBar.start(ProgressBar.java:379)
    at oracle.ide.dialogs.ProgressBar.start(ProgressBar.java:351)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.Model.saveEditSync(Model.java:337)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.Model.saveEditSync(Model.java:245)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.wizard.jaxrpc.TopDownWizard.runWizard(TopDownWizard.java:672)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.wizard.jaxrpc.TopDownWizard.runWizard(TopDownWizard.java:222)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.wizard.jaxrpc.TopDownWizard.invoke(TopDownWizard.java:164)
    at oracle.ide.wizard.WizardManager.invokeWizard(WizardManager.java:430)
    at oracle.ide.wizard.WizardManager$1.run(WizardManager.java:514)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.tools.weblogic.process.JDevWsdlGetTool.copyBindingFiles(JDevWsdlGetTool.java:292)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.tools.weblogic.process.JDevWsdlGetTool.copyFiles(JDevWsdlGetTool.java:131)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.tools.weblogic.WebLogicAdaptor.fetchWsdlExt(WebLogicAdaptor.java:1209)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.tools.WebServiceTools.fetchWsdlExt(WebServiceTools.java:424)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.tools.WebServiceTools$1.invoke(WebServiceTools.java:141)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.fetchWsdlExt(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.java.generator.CreateClasses.makeLocalWSDL(CreateClasses.java:519)
    ... 54 more

Sep 25, 2017 2:16:18 PM Generator handleExceptionImpl
WARNING: Fetching WSDL and mapping files failed for the following reason:
oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.GenerationException: Fetching WSDL and mapping files failed for the following reason:
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.java.generator.CreateClasses.makeLocalWSDL(CreateClasses.java:604)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.java.generator.CreateClasses.action(CreateClasses.java:184)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.generator.GeneratorAction.run(GeneratorAction.java:142)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at oracle.bali.ewt.dialog.JEWTDialog.runDialog(JEWTDialog.java:399)
    at oracle.bali.ewt.dialog.JEWTDialog.runDialog(JEWTDialog.java:360)
    at oracle.ide.dialogs.ProgressBar.start(ProgressBar.java:544)
    at oracle.ide.dialogs.ProgressBar.start(ProgressBar.java:395)
    at oracle.ide.dialogs.ProgressBar.start(ProgressBar.java:379)
    at oracle.ide.dialogs.ProgressBar.start(ProgressBar.java:351)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.Model.saveEditSync(Model.java:337)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.Model.saveEditSync(Model.java:245)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.wizard.jaxrpc.TopDownWizard.runWizard(TopDownWizard.java:672)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.wizard.jaxrpc.TopDownWizard.runWizard(TopDownWizard.java:222)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.wizard.jaxrpc.TopDownWizard.invoke(TopDownWizard.java:164)
    at oracle.ide.wizard.WizardManager.invokeWizard(WizardManager.java:430)
    at oracle.ide.wizard.WizardManager$1.run(WizardManager.java:514)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.tools.weblogic.process.JDevWsdlGetTool.copyBindingFiles(JDevWsdlGetTool.java:292)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.tools.weblogic.process.JDevWsdlGetTool.copyFiles(JDevWsdlGetTool.java:131)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.tools.weblogic.WebLogicAdaptor.fetchWsdlExt(WebLogicAdaptor.java:1209)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.tools.WebServiceTools.fetchWsdlExt(WebServiceTools.java:424)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.tools.WebServiceTools$1.invoke(WebServiceTools.java:141)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.fetchWsdlExt(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.java.generator.CreateClasses.makeLocalWSDL(CreateClasses.java:519)
    ... 54 more
```

I have not idea about what is happening, I have made a lot of service web with these option but now it's not working.
In the log there is a error with `Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` but I don't know what means.

Comment: It looks like it's having trouble finding the WSDL file you specified. Are there spaces in the folder path or WSDL name?

Comment: hmm. looking at the error more closely. It seems there might be an error with a binding lookup in your WSDL. I would double check your bindings & schema locations. If they all look good then you should show your WSDL in your question. Otherwise it will be hard for anyone to help you further.

Comment: I know this sounds crazy but maybe check the permissions of the folder that  it is trying to write to i.e. the actual drive folders.

Comment: Hi Steve, I want to say thank you because you were right. I found a space in my path. If you want, you can your answer and I'm going to put your answer like the correct. Thanks so much.